# Windows 7 won't boot with rEFInd

Tags: windows, partitioning, refit, refind

This is driving me nuts.

I have a Windows 7 install on my GPT partitioned drive. It's installed in EFI mode. I used the full hard drive trick to make Windows install the bootloader with the system (So instead of a System Reserved partition, the files are under C:/Windows/Boot/EFI). It works. What doesn't work is booting it from rEFInd.

What I've tried:

- Letting rEFInd find it automagically. Gets stuck on "Initializing and establishing link" in the Intel Boot Agent, then spouts "BootDevice Not Found"
- Making a manual Windows 7 entry. I've tried multiple ways: Copying the EFI folder to the Boot partition, setting volume to a UUID and using local references, setting volume to /dev/sda#, setting volume to the partition name. None of these work. If the EFI is on the Boot partition, it hangs with no information on screen, otherwise the file can't be found.

Anyone have any ideas I can try?

Answer (score 2):

After a bit of messing around, I managed to get the Windows Boot Manager to show up. It complained that it couldn't find the right file, and spat out the error code 0xc000000f. Googling this came up with a page, and one of the fixes listed was to run the setup again, select Repair, open the command prompt, and run `bootrec /rebuildbcd`. This actually worked, though it seemed to corrupt my `refind.conf`. It seems to work perfectly now, as all it did was add an extra folder to the EFI partition with the missing files (/Microsoft/Boot).